# php to connect Oracle. db enterprise edition on windows XP

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface, oracle8i

windows xp with oracle database enterprise 8i,
so i wana to write php scripts to connect to oracle database using xmapp 1.6.8
 even i uncomment the oci8 in php.ini
but error shown :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in ......


<?php

// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

sowhat is the problem ,is that compatibility issue or what

Comment: Which version of PHP comes with that XAMPP? And did you install OCI8?

Comment: php 5.2.6 ????? , nd wt do u mean by installing oci8 , isnt installed with oracle 8i enterprise and xampp

Comment: Did you go through this http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php yet?

Comment: yes i did  but i donw know what is exact problem ,but in the apache log PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_pgsql.dll' - This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.\r\n in Unknown on line 0 but i want to connect to oracle db not PostgreSQL

Comment: The error message about `undefined function` hints that your php runtime is missing the required extension. I'd try and check `phpinfo()` if OCI8 was loaded correctly.

Comment: i have checked it , and the results that oci8 is not found in phpinfo()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59889/discussion-between-zak-and-zsawyer).

Comment: Still the problem not  solved